# Windows Forms Webbrowser Full history

Tags: winforms, datagridview, browser, browser-history

I just want to show the full History of a `WinForms.Webbrowser`,
I know how to navigate forward and backward with

```
webBrowser1.Document.Window.History.Go/Back/Forward(1)
```

I just want to know how to visualize the History object, e.g in a DataGridView

```
DataGridView dgvChronic = new DataGridView();
dgvChronic.DataSource = webBrowser1.Document.Window.History;
```

but this doesn't work :/

I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
foreach (Link lk in webBrowser1.Document.Window.History)
{
    dgvChronic.Rows.Add(lk, "blabla");
}
```

My Solution:

```
private List<object> chronic = new List<object>();

    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Chronic hier erstellen
    if (tsURL.Text != webBrowser1.Url.ToString())
    {
        tsURL.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
        List<string> website = new List<string>();
        website.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        website.Add(tsURL.Text);
        chronic.Add(website);
    }
    }
```

Then to visualize the History:

```
foreach (List<string> website in chronic)
{
    dgvChronic.Rows.Add(website[0], website[1]);
}
```

ill mark trippinos Answer as accepted because its almost the same (i haven't tested it but it looks like it will work, too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be unsupported, but there is a quite simple workaround that requires few lines.
Take a look at this thread:
[msdn webbrowser thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/7abd91d0-05ee-47f1-af43-9b3fe6fffd57)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridView.DataSource` does not support `WebBrowser` `Hisory` type.
You should add each navigated URL to a `DataTable` and set this table to data source of `DataGridView`.

Comment: Okay, then How can i get the URLs out of The History?

Comment: if you mean to save the URL at the Navigating/Navigated or the document completed event this is a bad idea because they got triggert multiple times at one page change.